# rake strange behavior

Tags: ruby, rake, debian

I have installed the 'rake' rubygems on my Debian 5 / Ruby1.9 box and got the following error message:

```
> rake --version


gem_prelude.rb:114:in `push_gem_version_on_load_path': undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from gem_prelude.rb:8:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rake:18:in `<main>'
```

Any idea of the root cause of this problem ?

Comment: Are you using 1.9.0? That wasn't designed to be used "for real".

Comment: this is the one present in Debian repos.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Karmic Koala, and they have Ruby 1.9.1 as well as Ruby 1.9.0. Though it could be different between Debian and Ubuntu, or maybe you have a really old version of Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer here... Seems to be a bug with ruby 190...

http://singalong.posterous.com/rubygems-path-bug-with-ruby-190